# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Please try again.<nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Tags: error

Our whole production intranet is throwing this:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try
>   again.0x80004005 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot
>   complete this action.
>
> Please try
>   again.0x80004005
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try
>   again.0x80004005]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Boolean&
>   pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean&
>   pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String&
>   pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String&
>   pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte&
>   pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData,
>   Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String&
>   pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32&
>   pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid&
>   pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrContentTypeOrder) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Boolean&
>   pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean&
>   pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String&
>   pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String&
>   pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte&
>   pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData,
>   Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String&
>   pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32&
>   pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid&
>   pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrContentTypeOrder) +589
>
> [SPException: Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   +27609794    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Boolean&
>   pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean&
>   pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String&
>   pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String&
>   pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte&
>   pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData,
>   Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String&
>   pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32&
>   pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid&
>   pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrContentTypeOrder) +27998303
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32
>   pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean
>   fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, Byte&
>   verGhostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid&
>   docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level,
>   Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object&
>   buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState,
>   Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl,
>   Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId) +1750
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean
>   impersonate, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Byte& verGhostedPage, Guid& docId,
>   UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel,
>   String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl,
>   String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData,
>   SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot,
>   String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders,
>   Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes) +26513761
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetFileForRequest(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb web, Boolean exclusion, String virtualPath) +608
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.InitContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb web) +132
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext
>   context) +564
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.GetContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context) +27
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea) +918
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5446;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420

Nobody was doing anything unusual at the time.  It seems to have happened by itself.  The problem is isolated to one web app with a single site collection and the error seems to be happening at the site collection level but it's very hard to get any concrete information.

We copied the content database and attached it to another web application and got 403 errors.

Any ideas?

EDITED TO ADD:
here's the eventlog entry.  There's errors in the ULS as well but they're all much the same, unhanded COM exception.

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 11/16/2011 4:37:33 PM  Event time (UTC): 11/16/2011
>   9:37:33 AM  Event ID: 15e9272c47cb437f94823f604b0d8917  Event
>   sequence: 3214  Event occurrence: 15  Event detail code: 0
>   Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/36594234/ROOT-1-129659081407683408 
>       Trust level: WSS_Minimal 
>       Application Virtual Path: / 
>       Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\intra.aprc.undp.org80\ 
>       Machine name: TH-AS01    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 9732 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: UNDPTH\aprc.intranet    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: COMException 
>       Exception message: Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try
>   again.0x80004005
>   Request information: 
>       Request URL: https://intra.aprc.undp.org:443/default.aspx 
>       Request path: /default.aspx 
>       User host address: 172.19.94.74 
>       User:
>       Is authenticated: False 
>       Authentication Type:
>       Thread account name: UNDPTH\aprc.intranet    Thread information: 
>       Thread ID: 16 
>       Thread account name: UNDPTH\aprc.intranet 
>       Is impersonating: False 
>       Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Boolean&
>   pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean&
>   pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String&
>   pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String&
>   pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte&
>   pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData,
>   Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String&
>   pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32&
>   pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid&
>   pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrContentTypeOrder)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Boolean&
>   pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean&
>   pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String&
>   pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String&
>   pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte&
>   pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData,
>   Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String&
>   pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32&
>   pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid&
>   pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrContentTypeOrder)
>       Custom event details:

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer for a more detailed description of the error?

Comment: Check the free space on the content database and the disk itself. Completely random errors with no logical explanation are usually the cause of the DB server running out of space.

Comment: The database files are in the SAN and have, like, a terrabyte of free space.

This is only impacting *one* web app/site collection in the farm.  All the other apps/collections are doing fine.

Comment: I should also add that we're having a very difficult time recovering as the site collection won't mount/isn't recognised or something.  In central admin we can select the web application but the site collection comes up 'no selection'

Comment: Forgot to mention, it looks an awful lot like this problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937038/